# Number of notifications allowed in ios development mode

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I am using push notifications in iOS. But as my dot.net developer told me that the maximum number of notifications reached.
So my concern is how much notifications are allowed in one day in development mode.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Apple technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html):

> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs

[There's a limit to the size of the notification itself](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1):

> In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification
>   payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any
>   notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the
>   maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such limit for sending push notification. You can send as many push notification as you want.